# segregating array of structures which have void pointer

Tags: c, structure

First of all i am a new-bee to programming and i know only basics of c.

What i am trying to achieve is to segregate array of structures with structure having below declaration

```
 struct detail{
   int x;
   int y;
   int data_size;
   void *data;
 }
```

I am getting the array of structures of above type from serial communication. I need to segregate each struct and pass it to some other function.

What i have done till now is,

```
....

struct detail *read_first_element = (detail *) malloc (sizeof(detail)); // instance of defined struct

memcpy(read_first_element, SerialMessage->Data ,sizeof(detail)); // copy serial message into instance

for (int i=7;i>0;i--) // for example 7 struct data is coming in
{
   memcpy(current_element, SerialMessage->Data, 12); // fill first 3 elements (int int int)
// create memory for void *
  current_element->data = malloc (current_element->data_size);
  memcpy(current_element + 12, SerialMessage->Data + 12 , read_first_element->data_size );// fill the data
  size = read_first_element->data_size + 12; // create offset
  current_element = current_element + size; // for next structure 
  element

   some more code. . . . 
  }
```

Please let me know if i am doing it right? I do not have serial array structure coming in now but once connection is established i can test. Is there a way to test this with sample example?

Comment: [This might help you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/588800/setup-virtual-serial-ports-linux-null-modem-emulator-using-tty0tty)

Comment: I really don't think that a newbie should start with serial communication without some reading. There are plenty of issues here: Serial communication is stream based, so you need a Sync (2 to 4 bytes fixed value that you don't expect to appear in your data) at the beginning of messages in order to recognize where a structure starts. Communication in general should not rely on memcpy as each platform can place the data differently (big / little endian, byte alignment) resulting  in mismatching data. In addition, your code copies 1 structure size but your loop runs 7 times etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks o_weisman for your valuable comments i really appreciate it. For syncing in serial comm, header, tail, crc all have been added already and the segregation of data from that is taken care of.

Comment: Data contains pure data of array of struct format. The platform remains same as the boards have 2 modules of same type. The problem i am having is in running 7 times(just example) the loop so that the size is offset to read the next struct .

Comment: If as you say SerialMessage->Data is just a buffer of bytes that is guaranteed to be correctly copied to your structure, what is the problem to have a variable that holds your offset in the buffer? Instead of SerialMessage->Data you always use  SerialMessage->Data + OffsetInBuf and take care to increase OffsetInBuf by size of each data you read. Also, don't use numeric values, use a constant = 12.